# Checking for nulls in an integer data type

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, null

I have a line that is giving an error:
**Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'int'**

```
param[0].Value = form_request_id == null ? DBNull.Value.ToString() : form_request_id;
```

however, form_request_id is an int

How do I check for nulls in an int data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem isn't that you're checking for nulls in `form_request_id` (which will actually always evaluate to false since you really need to use an `int?` for the value to actually be null).

The real problem is that both sides of your conditional expression return different types (one is string and the other is int).

Since the `param[0].Value` should really be different types based on the condition...you're not going to be able to use the shortcut statement here. You'll have to spell it out the long way:

```
if(form_request_id == null)
    param[0].Value = DBNull.Value;
else
    param[0].Value = form_request_id;
```

As I mentioned before, you still need to use `int?` rather than `int` so that your variable can appropriately hold a null value. When you do that, you shouldn't even need the statement anymore because the database provider will see a null value and substitute `DBNull.Value` for you behind the scenes. The code would simply be:

```
param[0].Value = form_request_id;
```

Comment: Since form_request_id is an int, I had to modify your code to be "if(form_request_id == 0) "

Answer (score 3):

`int` is a value type and can not be `null` - it will default to `0`.

You can make an `int` nullable in two ways:

```
int? nullableInt = null;
```

Or,

```
Nullable<int> nullableInt = null;
```

Both options are fundamentally the same at the lowest level, I believe, with the former being shorthand for the latter.

This essentially gives the type a wrapper that exposes two useful properties, `HasValue` and `HasValue`. `HasValue` can be used to check whether the contained instance has a value *other* than `null`, `Value` allows you to retrieve the value.

Check the [MSDN page on `Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) for more information and examples.

As pointed out by @Justin Niessner, though, the error message you get relates not to this problem, but to the fact that `form_request_id` and `DBNull.Value.ToString()` are different types. If `form_request_id` is not `null`, then try calling `ToString` on that (or using some other mechanism to assign a value of desired, differing types.

Comment: removed the `var` keywords in the decleration, they aren't allowed there.

Comment: D your response is very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
param[0].Value = nullableInt ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably type of form_request_id is not int but

```
int?//or
Nullable<int>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define you int variable as a Nullable type and in order to check if it's null or not you need to use HasValue. In order to access the value of your nullable variable use `x.Value`

```
int? x = 10;

if (x.HasValue)
{
   //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an `int` type cannot be null. Default value of an int is 0 so you can check against 0 if you want to make sure its value has been set.